# What is Surface automation in RPA?

Tags: automation, uipath

I am learning RPA using tools such as UiPath and BluePrism. Can someone explain me what is surface automation(SA) techniques in RPA or direct me to the path where i can read more regarding SA techniques?

How does surface automation help in automating flash objects used in website ?

Thanks,
vds1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface automation in RPA means the process of creating automation according to images shown on a screen.

Surface automation is notoriously fragile and should be considered as a secondary method after programmatic solutions.

Surface automation is useful at least in two cases: when you can’t use controls programmatically (e.g. by element identifiers), or when the system under automation is changing (e.g. element identifiers are changing). It can also be faster than ’normal’ scripting.

In case of flash objects used in website, surface automation might be needed if there is no programmatic way to control or extract data from the object.

Surface automation techniques, such as optical character recognition (OCR) and object detection, are based on broader class of computer vision:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision

Comment: Just a small addition: In the context of UiPath, "Computer Vision" is a machine learning based component of the UiPath platform to identify interface elements of applications. See: https://www.uipath.com/de/product/platform/ai-computer-vision-for-rpa

Answer (score 0):

You can get Surface Automation related details in blue prism portal. Once login to the portal you can find a detailed set of documentsunder the Learning menu item:

Surface Automation - Autonomous Training Kit (ATK)
Training Document - Introduction to Surface Automation (v5)
Training Document - Surface Automation (v5)
Training Document - Introduction to Surface Automation (v4)
Training Document - Surface Automation (V4)
Introduction to Surface Automation (Win 10 and V5)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing and processing with the help of images. Image Comparison is major use of surface automation.

Comment: (From Review: Please elaborate a bit more. Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. This post is better suited as a comment to the question).